# Blocking a website on a router from a computer programatically

Tags: networking, router

In short, I want to prevent all computers on a network from accessing netflix until a certain condition is met. The user is supposed to solve a few problems on a program before being able to watch netflix. The user shouldn't be able to watch netflix on any device until after solving the problems.

How can I get the program to enable or disable access to netflix across the entire LAN? Perhaps there's a way to remotely configure these settings on the router? I am able to change the router's firmware or even purchase a new router if needed.

All advice appreciated.

Comment: Your requirement depends on router-specific features, if you wish to implement it at the router. What routers are available to you?

Comment: Also, without more information, your requirement may be poorly thought out. This access is enabled/disabled for the network as a whole, and a "solution" at any computer enables access for all? Then, the access is automatically revoked again after X time or at a certain time? Also, what can you trigger at the PC when the problem is "solved"? Can you run an arbitrary command?

Comment: Also, if this is triggered from any computer where the user has access to run the "problem" software as well as watch Netflix, what would stop them from manually running themselves whatever process the "solution" triggered to grant access? Without some rather complex security integrated into the problem workstations, that would be pretty hard to protect.

Comment: @shannon I have a ddwrt router but I can purchase another one if needed. Yes, I want access enabled/disabled for the network as a whole and I want the "solution" to enable access for them all. Access would be revoked at a certain time. Yes, when the problem is solved, I can trigger any command. I realize the solution wouldn't be extremely secure, but security isn't important at the moment. If a user is able to figure out what command to run and how to run it, then so be it. I just want to build a proof of concept.

Comment: Routers don't see what users are on their network.  They see what computers are on the network.  In your question you propose the question as if a specific user is accessing the questions on multiple devices.  Are you trying to block just that user or all the computers regardless of the user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're proposing is essentially the same system that many airports and coffee shops use to restrict access to the web on their networks, unless a user completes a task.

Functionally, there are a few commercial providers that do this:

- [Boingo](http://www.boingo.com/)
- [Aptilo](https://www.aptilo.com/airport-wifi)
- [And others via this Forbes article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/alexkonrad/2014/01/22/airport-wifi-free/)

For what you want, it is a combination of hardware and software to achieve your goals. Your network layout will be similar to [this network diagram](http://dnsredirector.com/networks/02/), which shows:

- Client computers
- Server that provides DNS resolution and hosts a website
- A switch
- A modem / internet access point

The process will include your DNS server returning a fake IP address (such as `1.2.3.4`) for the page the user requests, unless the user is authorized to pass. It is the same from a tech standpoint as [DNS hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking). Your webserver (which is at `1.2.3.4`) will then return the page asking the user to complete the activity before being allowed to pass.

I'd suggest looking into this software for what you need:

- [Squid proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/)
- [Open DD WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)
- [This Wikipedia list of router / firewall software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_and_firewall_distributions)
- And an [Ardiuno](http://www.arduino.cc/) for the hardware portion since you can modify it a lot more than commercial routers

Comment: awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you clarify what the role of the Arduino is? (I'm familiar with Arduino).

Comment: The entire system relies on DNS resolution for the network being under your control. This requires DNS resolution software to run on *something* physical. You can use an off-the-shelf router, but your best bet, because you are already modifying the software, is to get a similarly modifiable hardware. Arduino is a good platform for modifying hardware and software.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about your scale of your network , and what are the mediums are used to watch that program.

but for an overall solution you can use **[OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/)** to Protect Your Entire Network

OpenDNS is free for use at home, and a more powerful version is available to **businesses for a fee**. OpenDNS is installed into your network’s router, and affects all network traffic. This means that it blocks websites on any device connected to the router, including computers, tablets, game consoles, and mobile phones.

Once you have OpenDNS configured, you’re ready to start setting your filters. These filters will block sites that meet certain criteria, such as pornography, academic fraud, social media, and many more. You can either filter out categories, set overall tiers of protection, block specific websites, or only allow specific websites. 
(in your case it might be https://www.netflix.com/global)

Once you’ve enabled your filters, you can monitor the web usage on your network to see if people are trying to access sites that they shouldn’t. To do this, you will first need to ensure that stat logging is enabled. Log in to the Dashboard and click the Settings tab. Check the box labeled “Enable stats and logs” and then click apply.

if you don;t know exactly what are the sites your network users are using to watch the program , you can install a  Web Monitoring Program like Net-Nanny.
 then try the rest . good luck.

Comment: This solution is probably not reliable to meet the need due to the need to revoke access at an unknown time.

Comment: FYI, the problem will be when the browser is already open and receiving a video, for example. There's the matter of DNS cache, which can be addressed by setting a short timeout, but there's also the matter of active connections, and possible numeric-IP-based load balancing schemes at the provider.

Comment: I agree though, that is would be unlikely to be possible to browse for and start a new video from Netflix after the DNS was deactivated. Of course, you'd still need a way to actually remotely activate and deactivate that rule.

Comment: +1 : I did a little research myself, and despite the shortcomings, this may be the best bet for the OP's proof-of-concept. OpenDNS on DD-WRT. Two scripts to configure OpenDNS; netflixon.sh, netflixoff.sh. netflixoff.sh is run via a cron job, and netflixon.sh is run in response to a custom web page requested from the router ( http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WEB_server )